# Draw a series of rotated lines with HTML canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to draw a polyline like this

[image]

from an array consisting of sets of angles and lengths (50 and 100, 90 and 20, 90 and 30 etc..)

Any ideas?

Comment: Google for "axonometric projection"; or simply apply rotation and non-uniform scaling to your context prior to drawing your lines. Also, bone up on your trigonometry; keep track of your current heading (like Logo) and use `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` to decompose into local coordinates.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure how your sample data is supposed to correlated to your drawing. How do you know that `90` means turning left or right, given that it appears to mean both in your drawing?

Comment: That's a good point. I guess you could say that 90 is right and 180 is left. But I think it would make more sense to add a "left" and "right" to the dataset which wouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 6):

that was a hard one ...

e.g array of objects of angle & lengths:

```
var arr = [
    { angle: 0, h: 50 },
    { angle: 90, h: 60 },
    { angle: 180, h: 70 },
    { angle: 270, h: 80 },
    { angle: 180, h: 90 }
];
```

the following draw method will draw the lines from the previous array,

```
function getAngle(ctx, x, y, angle, h) {
    var radians = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    return { x: x + h * Math.cos(radians), y: y + h * Math.sin(radians) };
}
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.beginPath();

        var pos = { x: 400, y: 400 };

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
            pos = getAngle(ctx, pos.x, pos.y, arr[i].angle, arr[i].h);
            ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

you can call the draw after the canvas element

```
<div style="width:800px;height:800px;border:solid 1px red;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    draw();
</script>
```

EDIT:
try changing draw function to this,

```
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.beginPath();

        var pos = { x: 400, y: 400 },
            angle = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            angle += arr[i].angle;
            angle = (arr[i].angle + angle) % 360;

            ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
            pos = getAngle(ctx, pos.x, pos.y, arr[i].angle + angle, arr[i].h);
            ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great - almost there! Now we just need the turns to be relative to the endpoint of the previous line. Thoughts?

Comment: You need to use ctx.rotate and ctx.translate

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as Morten J and tried Shlomi Komemi's second draw function and it works fine ... but only for the Array he gave with only multiples of 90°.
However, if you try 30° you will notice that something is wrong because a right angle is drawn.
I figured out that the reason for this is that angle and arr[i].angle are summed up 3 times.
Here is the corrected version of the function:

```
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.beginPath();

        var pos = { x: 400, y: 400 },
        angle = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            angle = (arr[i].angle + angle) % 360;

            ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
            pos = getAngle(ctx, pos.x, pos.y, angle, arr[i].h);
            ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

That should work (but I guess the Morten does not care after 3 years...).